# Loop through range of dates and adding corresponding cells input

Tags: vba, excel

I have an range of input like shown on image 1. If i give an Start date and end date on the another sheet, the vba will run through and i need to get output like shown in the image 2. I can specify any date as a range of date in the next sheet. There is duplication of date in the range of inputs. How to give date loop for this scenario and remove duplicates in the name to add the time and get the desired output.

`

```
Sub dateloop()

Dim sd As Date
Dim ed As Date
Dim asd As Range

sd = Sheets(1).Range("b2") .Value
ed = Sheets(1).Range("b3").Value

For asd = sd To ed
MsgBox asd.Value
Next asd

End Sub    `
```

I tried the above code but it didn't loop through the range of dates.

```
Sub looprange()   
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim MyCell As Range

Set MyRange = Sheets("input").Range("A1:a40000")


For Each MyCell In MyRange

  If MyCell.Value >= Sheets("output").Range("b2").Value And _
  MyCell.Value <= Sheets("output").Range("b3").Value Then

  Sheets("output").Range("b5").offset(1,0) = Mycell.offset(0,1).Value

    End If


  Next x
End Sub
```

I tried above coding also but i didn't worked. Can someone help me to get the Output.

Input:

[image: Input]

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Date loops are no different to any other - `For variable = start_value To end_value Step increment`

Comment: There are a lot of ways you could go about not including duplicate dates. An example might be something like `If current_cell_date <> last_cell_date Then do stuff End If` somewhere inside your loop. What code have you tried? Can you include it in your question?

Comment: Dear Tyler  I'm a beginner. I'm trying to develop codes. Sure i'll tell what code i used for

Comment: Sub dateloop()

Dim sd As Date
Dim ed As Date
Dim asd As Range

sd = Sheets(1).Range("b2").Value
ed = Sheets(1).Range("b3").Value
For asd = sd To ed

MsgBox asd.Value

Next BR
  
End Sub

Comment: @Balachandar, please add the code to your original question (there is an edit button). indent the code by 4 spaces so that it shows up as code. then delete your last comment

Comment: @Tyeler, Added the code i used, please help me out to get the output.

Comment: @jsotola, Added the code i used, please help me out to get the output.

Comment: you can "easily" do this without VBA with PIvotTable https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576

Comment: @Slai I know pivot option is there, but it's redundant to create a pivot every time when i need data's of different dates. This one is simple, the other users will also understand what i done and they will get the data they want at different dates just by typing the days they want and run the code. Thanks for the link.,,,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Combine Unique Values Based Off Two Criteria

---

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit
'Option Explicit is very helpful because it will throw an error on compile if
'you have undefined variables floating around in your project.

Sub LoopRange()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Faster runtime

Dim iWS As Worksheet: Set iWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input")
Dim oWS As Worksheet: Set oWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output")

Dim inputRange As Range: Set inputRange = iWS.Range("A3", iWS.Range("A3").End(xlDown))
Dim outputRange As Range: Set outputRange = oWS.Range("A6", oWS.Range("A6").End(xlDown))
Dim fullOpRange As Range

Dim startDate As Date: startDate = oWS.Range("B2").Value
Dim endDate As Date: endDate = oWS.Range("B3").Value

Dim cRow As Long: cRow = 5
Dim oRow As Long: oRow = 7
Dim iCell As Range, oCell As Range

'Build the output range on the Output worksheet that falls between defined dates.
For Each iCell In inputRange
    If iCell.Value >= startDate And iCell.Value <= endDate Then
        cRow = cRow + 1
        oWS.Range("A" & cRow).Value = iCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        oWS.Range("B" & cRow).Value = iCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
        oWS.Range("C" & cRow).Value = iCell.Offset(0, 3).Value
    End If
Next iCell

Set fullOpRange = oWS.Range("A5:C" & oWS.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row)

'Sort the output range
fullOpRange.Sort oWS.Range("A6"), xlAscending, oWS.Range("B6"), , xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
fullOpRange.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

'Add duplicate matching Name/Type and delete excess
Do
    If oWS.Range("A" & oRow).Value = oWS.Range("A" & oRow - 1).Value And oWS.Range("B" & oRow).Value = oWS.Range("B" & oRow - 1).Value Then
        oWS.Range("C" & oRow - 1).Value = oWS.Range("C" & oRow - 1).Value + oWS.Range("C" & oRow).Value
        oWS.Range("A" & oRow).EntireRow.Delete xlUp
    Else
        oRow = oRow + 1
    End If
Loop While oRow <> oWS.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1

Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'Do not forget to turn this back on!
End Sub
```

---

**Explanation**

The first thing I did was transfer the applicable data that falls between the desired dates, from the Input worksheet to the Output worksheet.

Next I wanted to sort this data by Name and Type to make cycling through the output range faster.

After that it's as simple as comparing the current row's data to the previous row, and looping through to the end.

---

**Comments with a mini-answer**

The above code should function in the way you desire. There's a lot more room for expanding on this code to make it more user friendly for multiple uses, but I'll leave that to you. It seems like you may not have a grasp of the basics and if this is true, I strongly suggest reading up on a few tutorials that cover expressions you want to use. It will save you a lot of time and headache if you can get a good understanding of basic programming expressions.

As an example, you said that the following code did not loop through your range of dates. I included comments to help you see why this wouldn't work with your structure of `For Loop`:

```
Sub dateloop()

    Dim sd As Date
    Dim ed As Date
    Dim asd As Range

    sd = Sheets(1).Range("b2").Value
    ed = Sheets(1).Range("b3").Value

    For asd = sd To ed     'For Range = Date To Date
        MsgBox asd.Value   'MsgBox Range.Value (Range was never defined)
    Next asd               'Next Range

End Sub
```

The way you're trying to use the `For Loop` is incorrect. The following code *works* but doesn't really help you achieve your end goal:

```
Sub dateloop()

    Dim sd As Date
    Dim ed As Date
    Dim asd As Date '<----Date

    sd = Sheets(2).Range("b2").Value
    ed = Sheets(2).Range("b3").Value

    For asd = sd To ed 'For Date = Date To Date
        MsgBox asd '<----remove .Value
    Next asd

End Sub
```

A different way to approach the `For Loop` that is more useful to your project:

```
Sub dateloop()

    Dim sd As Date
    Dim ed As Date
    Dim asd As Range '<----Range

    sd = Sheets(2).Range("b2").Value
    ed = Sheets(2).Range("b3").Value

    For Each asd In Sheets(1).Range("A3:A20") 'For Each Range in Range
        If asd.Value >= sd And asd.Value <= ed Then _
            MsgBox asd.Value
    Next asd

End Sub
```

I hope this helps. If you have any questions on what the code I provided is doing, or if there are any issues with it, please let me know. Good luck!

Comment: It's really helpful. I am working on it. Since i was a basic and learning VBA on my own i'm not able to get through most of that, That's the problem. Sure i'll comment here when i got the output. Thanks for pointing errors in my previous codes. I'll go through tutorials and online classes to clear my doubts soon.

Comment: I worked the project today and got the needed results and it helped to get more understanding on codes. Thanks a lot again for teaching me. I'm interested to go further on VBA. I'll let you know if any help needed from you, Thanks,.....

Comment: If my answer has answered your question, could you mark it as such? Thank you and good luck!

Comment: yeah your answer worked exactly as they are, Awesome coding.

Comment: Lol I mean click the check mark at the top left of my answer. Thanks again.